# Robot Framework - Import library with 2 classes from different location

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a custom library that is in a different location from the test suite.
Meaning the test suite is in "C:/Robot/Test/test_suite.txt" and my library is in "C:/Robot/Lib/library.py".

The library has 2 different classes and I need to import both of them.

I have tried to import it by "Library | ../Lib/library.py" but I got an error saying that the library contains no keywords.
I also tried to import it by "Library | ../Lib/library.Class1" but got a syntax error.

Is there any way to do it without changing the PYTHONPATH?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices for importing:

- importing a library via PYTHONPATH
- importing a library based on the file path to the library.

In the first case you can import each class separately.

In the second case, it's not possible to import multiple classes from a single file. If you give a path to a python file, that file must contain keywords. It can *also* include classes, but robot won't know about those classes.